# interp2 function in python similar to MATLAB interp2

Tags: python, matlab

I am new to python and an amateur programmer so please bear with me.  Right now I have a matrix which is 15x9.  I essentially want to expand this matrix such that it contains more values.  Thus I want to interpolate this data a number times, similar to the interp2 function in MATLAB which allows you to interpolate n times.
If you could perhaps show me a function that perform this task or even steps as to how to solve this problem any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry I should have stated this before, but yes I am using a numpy array, not a list.

Comment: you have a "matrix" -- Is that a numpy array?  A list of lists?  If you're not using `numpy`, you should definitely start if you're planning on porting matlab code.

Comment: Second vote for numpy, and I'd add scipy to the mix. I don't know the particulars of interp2, since there are many ways to interpolate data, but you should check this http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html

Comment: Currently I am using both numpy and scipy.  I have checked out scipy's interpolation methods however, unlike MATLABs interpolation interp2 method, none of these interpolation methods specifically take an argument to interpolate n times.  MATLABs interp2 method: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "an argument to interpolate n times"? Can you give a matlab example?

Comment: Well based on the documentation provide by MATLAB for the interp2 function when it comes to interpolating n times it provides this explanation: "ZI = interp2(Z,ntimes) expands Z by interleaving interpolates between every element, working recursively for ntimes. interp2(Z) is the same as interp2(Z,1)."

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same issue, and figured out that `scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates` does the same as `Vq = interp2(V,Xq,Yq)`. Please read the documentation of these commands to find out the solution for your case.

Try this for Matlab's `Vq = interp2(V,Xq,Yq)` :

```
Vq = scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates(V, [Xq.ravel(), Yq.ravel()], order=3, mode='nearest').reshape(V.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use griddata from scipy.

Tutorial here: 
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html

Comment: I know that griddata exist, but I don't think you have answered my question.  I am looking for an interpolation function that can interpolate N times.  I do not see any reference to this in the griddata documentation.  If it does exist can you please point it out for me.